# how i can update parent row (foreign key)

Tags: mysql

in mysql database i have tow tabel , between them relationship "foreign key"
when i want need update row but : show this missage

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(paymesomething.advertisers, CONSTRAINT advertisers_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY 
(advertiser_id) REFERENCES jobs (advertiser_id))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to update `jobs.advertiser_id`, or delete a row in `jobs`, but there's at least one row in `paymesomething` that has an `advertisers` column that references it as a foreign key. The update would invalidate the relationship, so it's not allowed.

You can add `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` to the foreign key declaration in `paymesomething`. Then when you change the parent table, it will automatically delete or update the related rows in `paymesomething`.

Comment: and sorry becase :
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.